# Convert escaped characters with python

Tags: python, json, escaping

First sorry for my english

I have to convert strings from a json file like the following:

```
{"detalle":"el Expediente N\u00b0\u00a030 de la Resoluci\u00f3n 11..."}
```

In something like:

```
{"detalle":"el Expediente N° 30 de la Resolución 11..."}
```

to then write it in a txt.

I tried:

```
json.dumps({"detalle":"el Expediente N\u00b0\u00a030 de la Resoluci\u00f3n 11..."}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

that returns

```
'{"detalle": "el Expediente N\\\\u00b0\\\\u00a030 de la Resoluci\\\\u00f3n 11..."}'
```

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In this answer, I'm assuming you use Python 2.)

First, let me explain why your snippet returns something different than you expect:

```
r1 = json.dumps({"detalle":"el Expediente N\u00b0\u00a030 de la Resoluci\u00f3n 11..."}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
print(r1)
r2 = json.dumps({"detalle":u"el Expediente N\u00b0\u00a030 de la Resoluci\u00f3n 11..."}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
print(r2)
```

This outputs:

```
{"detalle": "el Expediente N\\u00b0\\u00a030 de la Resoluci\\u00f3n 11..."}
{"detalle": "el Expediente N° 30 de la Resolución 11..."}
```

The difference is, that in the first case, the input string is ascii code, with slashes and other characters to represent special characters, and in the second case, the string is a unicode string with unicode characters. The second case is what you want.

Based on this, here is what I understand from your problem:

Normally when you read a JSON file with the `json` module, the strings (which are escaped in the JSON file) are unescaped by the parser. If you still see escaped characters, that indicates that the strings were (accidentally?) double escaped in the JSON file. In that case, try an extra unescape with `s.decode('unicode-escape')`:

```
data["detalle"] = data["detalle"].decode('unicode-escape')
```

Once you have proper unicode strings loaded in Python, converting them to bytes with `s.encode('utf8')` and writing the result to a file, is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with python2.7 i tried data["detalle"].decode('unicode-escape') and I get "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 15-16: ordinal not in range(128)" and in python3 "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Comment: I can't reproduce that I'm afraid. If I understand correctly, you are reading a JSON file, and want to write a similar file, but with non-ascii characters instead of escaped characters. Is the input text you provided the content of the file you are reading, or a print() of the data in Python? It would help if you can edit your question to clarify your input and expected output: a one-line mini-version of your input file, a one-line mini-version of the output file you expect, and the code snippet that gives you an error instead of the result your expected.

Comment: BTW, since Python 3 has better unicode support, I suggest using Python 3. `str` objects in Python 3 don't have a `.decode()` method, because `.decode()` works on `bytes`, producing `str`. Once I understand your input and desired output better, we can see what is needed to get it working.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay I have a lot of work.  I was wrong, you are right this is the solution.  Thank you very much.